# `Run-time error 6: Overflow` if the Name of file is > 2139999999

Tags: excel, vba

The below function do the following: 
`Get the full path of file which name is numbers only` **highest number** , on current Folder. 
It is works normally until file name is greater than 2139999999 , e.g  2149999999.xlsb
The error raised on this line    `If lngNb < CLng(Split(El, ".")(0)) Then`
**Note**: I am using office 2016 32Bit on windows 10 64Bit. 
Appreciate for yours comments and answers.

```
Function Path_of_Highest_Numeric_Name(strFold As String, Optional strext As String = "*.*") As String
    Dim arrD, i As Long, lastName As String, lngNb As Long, El
    'Return all files name in an array
    arrD = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strext & """ /b").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    If UBound(arrD) = -1 Then MsgBox "Nothing could be found in the path you supplied...": Exit Function
    arrD(UBound(arrD)) = "@@##": arrD = Filter(arrD, "@@##", False) 'Remove the last (empty) element
 
    For Each El In arrD   'iterate between the array elements
            If IsNumeric(Split(El, ".")(0)) Then
                'Compare the lngNb variable (initially 0) with the numeric value:
                If lngNb < CLng(Split(El, ".")(0)) Then
                     'addapt lngNb like the bigger number
                     lngNb = CLng(Split(El, ".")(0)): lastName = El
                End If
            End If
    Next
            Path_of_Highest_Numeric_Name = strFold & lastName 'Build the necessary path
End Function
```

**It can be tested in the next way:**

```
Debug.Print Path_of_Highest_Numeric_Name("C:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\", "*.xls*")
```

Comment: Use Double instead of Long and CDbl

Comment: [Long Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) in VBA can only store numbers within the range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. The obvious work-around is to not convert the string into a number, and just convert pieces of the string for comparison and editing.

Comment: @Rory ,in addition the below answer, your suggestions works perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum number a `Long` can hold (as it is a signed 32bit number) is 2,147,483,647 - therefore you get the overflow.

You could, as Rory suggest, switch to a Double as it has more significant digits.
I would suggest you don't deal with numbers at all - at the end you return a string anyhow.

The following logic compares strings. To prevent that "9" > "10", the logic is if a string is longer, it is larger. If both strings have the same length, you can compare them.

The function `IsNumeric`, btw, works correctly no matter how long your string (=filename) is.

```
Dim largestNumber As String, newNumber As String, fileWithLargestNumber As String
largestNumber = ""

For Each El In arrD   'iterate between the array elements
    newNumber = Split(El, ".")(0)
    If IsNumeric(newNumber) Then
        If Len(largestNumber) < Len(newNumber) _
        Or (Len(largestNumber) = Len(newNumber) And largestNumber < newNumber) Then
            largestNumber = newNumber
            fileWithLargestNumber = El
        End If
    End If
Next

Path_of_Highest_Numeric_Name = strFold & fileWithLargestNumber
```

Comment: It works brilliant, I got it. It will be helpful if you post full function, may be other one benefit.

Comment: Sorry, was so focused on comparing the strings (numbers) that I forgot about the full filename. Updated the code.